# Plane equation rewriting

Tags: vector-spaces

We know that a line can be written as $ ⟨x,y,z⟩ = ⟨x_0,y_0,z_0⟩ + t⟨a,b,c⟩ $ where $ x_0, y_0, z_0 $ is a point on the line and $ ⟨a, b, c⟩$ is a direction vector of the line. In a similar way, a plane can be written as $ ⟨x,y,z⟩ = ⟨x_0,y_0,z_0⟩ + s⟨a,b,c⟩ + t⟨d,e,f⟩ $ where $ x_0,y_0,z_0 $ is a point on the plane and $ ⟨a,b,c⟩,⟨d,e,f⟩ $ are two non-parallel direction vectors in the plane. Write the plane $ ⟨x, y, z⟩ = ⟨2, 1, −3 ⟩ +s⟨1, 0, 2⟩ + t⟨0, −1, 3⟩ $ in the form $ ax + by + cz = d $.

So I have this question for my Calculus 2 course. I don’t know how to approach this question. Anyone that can help me out?

Comment: Do you mean $$[x,y,z]=[2,1,-3]+s[1,0,2]+t[0,-1,3]$$?

Comment: Has your question been answered? If yes, you should accept an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following approach.

Find a vector that is normal to your plane of interest, let's call it $\vec n$.
You can find it as the cross product of any two vectors that are parallel to your plane. Keep in mind that these two vectors **must not be parallel to each other**. Luckily, the plane is defined by two such vectors, namely $(a,b,c)$ and $(d,e,f)$, so we have
$$\vec n = (a,b,c) \times (d,e,f)$$

Now, consider any point $(x,y,z)$. It lies on the plane if and only if the vector $(x-x_0, y-y_0, z-z_0)$ is perpendicular to the normal vector $\vec n$. Recall that two non-zero vectors are perpendicular to each other if and only if their dot product is equal to **zero**. Note that if you have $(x,y,z) = (x_0,y_0,z_0)$, the point $(x,y,z)$ lies on the plane anyway so you don't have to treat this as a special case.

Solving

$$\vec n \cdot (x-x_0,y-y_0,z-z_0) = 0$$
you will arrive at an equation containing $x$, $y$, $z$ and some constant terms. From this equation, you can easily identify $A$, $B$, $C$ and $D$ of the desired equation
$$Ax+By+Cz = D$$

Comment: I would suggest this same route.

Answer (score 0):

Another way: 
$<x, y, z>= <2, 1, 3>+ s<1, 0, 2>+ t<0, -1, 3>= <2+ s, 1- t, 3+ 3s+ 3t>$.  That is, x= 2+ s, y= 1- t, and z= 3+ 3s+ 3t. From the first two equations, s= x- 2 and t= 1- y.  Putting those into the third equation z= 3+ 3(x- 2)+ 3(1- y)= 3+ 3x- 6+ 3- 3y which is the same as 3x- 3y- z= 0.